# What is a better way to authenticate some of the routes on Express 4 Router?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, routes, passport.js

I'm using Express 4 where I have a route protected by passport.js, like this:

```
var media = require('express').Router();

media.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // provide results from db
});

media.post('/', passport.authenticate('bearer'), function(req, res) {
    // This route is auth protected
});
```

So - get collection routes should (mostly) not be protected for me, and create/update routes should. But this requires me to pass passport to all my route files (I have 7 so far), then to add that as a middleware to some of them.

I like the version where you can do something like this:

```
var router = require('./my-router');
app.use('/api/route', passport.authenticate('bearer'));
app.use('/api/route', router);
```

But this would require auth on **all** my routes.

Is there a better way then to pass passport all the way around?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could split your router up into protected/unprotected and call the middleware on the protected routes.

```
var express = require('express'),
    media = express.Router(),
    mediaProtected = express.Router();

media.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // provide results from db
});

mediaProtected.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // This route is auth protected
});

module.exports = {
    protected: mediaProtected,
    unprotected: media
};
```

And then you can do

```
var router = require('./my-router');
app.use('/api/route', passport.authenticate('bearer'), router.protected);
app.use('/api/route', router.unprotected);
```

Comment: Wow, Ben, that's actually pretty smart! I just need to fix naming there.

Comment: This would be genius, only it doesn't work when the route paths are the same. I've tried this same implementation on express4, passport 0.3.2, and the check on authentication follows the route path, not the router instance. All routes in this case are being protected for me.

Comment: It won't work if the route paths are the same, how is it going to know which one you want to use? The first route you define will take precedence.

Comment: @BenFortune what was your final solution?