# Express app.use() with 2 middleware cannot work together

Tags: express

I am trying to apply "Basic Auth" OR "Bearer Token" to all routes started with "/auth"

In the same router file "routes/auth.js", I prepared the 2 router types and exported them together. Then in "app.js", I am trying to apply both middleware to "app.use()".

The result is, not both types are working at the same time. Only the 1st position middleware is affecting all "/auth" routes, that is:-

```
app.use('/auth', [affecting-all-auth-routes, no-effect-on-all-auth-routes]);
```

These are the reference sites that I tried:-
http://expressjs.com/zh-tw/api.html#app.use

```
app.use('/', [r1, r2]);
```

[What is a better way to authenticate some of the routes on Express 4 Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602948/what-is-a-better-way-to-authenticate-some-of-the-routes-on-express-4-router)

I guess it may due to some syntax error. Could you please give me some idea?

// app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();

app.use('/auth', [authRouter.basic, authRouter.bearer]);
```

// routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
var routerBasic = express.Router();
var routerBearer = express.Router();

const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const jwtProtected = require('./middleware/jwToken');

routerBasic.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'admin': '1234' }
}))
routerBearer.use(jwtProtected);

const login = require('../controllers/Auth/Basic/login');
const tokenRevoke = require('../controllers/Auth/Token/revoke-token');

routerBasic.post('/login', login);
routerBearer.post('/token/revoke', tokenRevoke);

module.exports = {
    basic: routerBasic,
    bearer: routerBearer
}
```

Comment: Did you tried like this(without []): ` app.use('/auth', affecting-all-auth-routes, no-effect-on-all-auth-routes);
 `

Comment: I have tried, but not help...

Comment: Can you show your middleware function code???

Answer (score 0):

After a days research, I finally got the answer.

I shall not separate auth type at router level, it shall be at route level:-

```
router.post('/login', basicAuthFunctionHere, login);
router.post('/token/revoke', jwtAuthFunctionHere, tokenRevoke);
```